# How can I horizontally and vertically center this four divs contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, alignment

I am trying to horizontally and vertically center contents in 4 divs. If I horizontally center the contents then vertical center just gone. If I vertically center the contents then horizontal center just gone.

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://goo.gl/vvhzzl)

The DIV, part1 is vertically centered and part2, part3 and part4 horizontally centered.

I want all 4 divs contents to be centered vertically and horizontally.
How can I do that?

Also some colorful style suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with part1?

Comment: Part1 is NOT HORIZONTALLY aligned. You can see that when you resize the window..Actually aligned same as others.. but it's not working as expected,,..

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. Probably browser specific. Try to add a screenshot and details of your browser.

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/20f51dy.jpg I'm using firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.goals has a style applied, but .skills, .rrhelp, and .cur_possi do not. You also need `position:relative` on .part1, .part2, .part3, .part4. In order to make the text properly centered, since you are setting the .goals, .skills, .rrhelp, and .cur_possi divs to `position: absolute`, add `left: 0; right: 0;`

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/21s5u8ys/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can give fix height in pixel and `overflow:hidden;`

I have update fiddle , may be this help to you : http://jsfiddle.net/21s5u8ys/3/

Comment: this is not VERTICALLY aligned